# how can I support http_proxy or logic control in Dockerfile during docker build?

Tags: docker

I work in company environment which has firewall, mostly I need proxy to access external to update the packages

While I want to keep the same Dockerfile to be build inside/outside of the company.

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
# for inside 
RUN echo 'Acquire::http::Proxy "http://<proxy>";' > /etc/apt/apt.conf
# for external
#RUN echo '#Acquire::http::Proxy "http://<proxy>";' > /etc/apt/apt.conf
RUN apt-get update
```

How can I achieve this during `docker build`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note this feature was added in docker >= 1.9.0 https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/14634

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have logic in the Dockerfile, however your Dockerfile can `ADD` a script (in shell, python, ...) and `RUN` that script at build time.

Note that doing this makes your Dockerfile more difficult to understand by others who will not suspect different images to be built depending on context. You'd better write a clear comment in the Dockerfile just before the `RUN` command.

### http proxy when building an image

Now if your only issue is with proxies, you should not have to deal with such things in your Dockerfile. Instead run the Docker daemon with the `HTTP_PROXY` environment variable set. (there are answered questions on that matter)

### http proxy when running a container

You can tell the process which is run by a container to use a http proxy by injecting environment variable to the container with the `-e` option of the `docker run` command. 
Refer to the documentation of the command which is run in your container to discover if it obeys the `HTTP_PROXY` environment variable. Note that some processes need the `http_proxy` environnement variable in lower case.

Comment: good suggestion. for `http_proxy`, is it in `/etc/default/docker` ? can it work for container inside ?

Comment: `/etc/default/docker` is good place to set this environment variable. I updated my answer with details on how to pass an environment variable to a container

Comment: I don't think the http_proxy in /etc/default/docker can effect the build Dockerfile & run the container. good to know run supports this. there is https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/issues/4962 discussion on how to support http_proxy for build

Comment: I guess that where the logic in the build script kicks in. It could detect the need for a proxy and set an environment variable for subsequent commands in that script. (the build script you ADD and RUN,  not the Dockerfile)

Comment: In fact I have the issue when *building* images although http_proxy is set properly for the docker daemon (e.g. I can pull images remotely without problems). That's because I think that building an image is done within the context of the BASE image and http_proxy is not propagated into this build image. Indeed I have to explicitely set ENV http_proxy e.g. for running wget to fetch things. Any idea here ? That's really annoying e.g for publishing automated builds on registry.hub.docker.io